# how to get all children from element js

Tags: javascript

how to get all chilredn from elemnt on javascript pure:

i have this code:

```
  const selectFaturamento = document.querySelector("div#faturamento");
  const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");
  const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
```

I basically need to get all the elements: .options-container
.option

but they are children of my element: select

why do I have other elements that are not children that have the same class

Answer (score 0):

When using `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`, it uses the `document` as the parent. If you are looking for children of a specific selector, you can use that one instead of `document` to search inside of that node. For example:

```
  const selectFaturamento = document.querySelector("div#faturamento");
  const optionsContainer = selectFaturamento.querySelector(".options-container");
  const optionsList = optionsContainer.querySelectorAll(".option");
```

Comment: this dont work i got null value on optionsContainer.

Comment: Sounds like the markup is different then. Is the class `options-container` maybe on the same element as the `div` with `id="faturamento"`? `item.querySelector` will look in the children of `item` only

Comment: yes it is a child and it does not work I already tested it with other elements that are also children.

Comment: I guess you need to show the markup then. For example to select all names of the comments to this answer, I can do `const thisAnswer = document.querySelector("div#answer-62867555"); const allComments = thisAnswer.querySelector(".comments"); const users = allComments.querySelectorAll(".comment-user");` and have them saved in `users`